# ec2-register Client.null: null

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

I am trying to resgister an amazon image, and I keep getting the error `Client.null: null.`

I am able to browse to the URL and see the xml file.

The command I execute is:

```
ec2-register output.raw.manifest.xml -U <URL>
Client.null: null
```

any idea what could be the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that this command is used to register instance store images rather than EBS back images.

Usually the xml file with a series of 10GB files are uploaded to S3 prior to registering the AMI. Are you sure the bundle is in one of your S3 buckets?

Did you run something like this from the instance you want to create the image from?:

```
ec2-bundle-vol -d /<someplace-where-you-have-a-lot-of-space> -k YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY -c YOUR_CERTIFICATE -u YOUR_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
ec2-upload-bundle -b YOUR_BUCKET_NAME -m output.raw.manifest.xml -a YOUR_ACCESS_KEY -s YOUR_SECRET_KEY
```

Then you can run:
    ec2-register output.raw.manifest.xml

You can also register your image from the AWS console once you have created the bundle like shown here:

[image: Register Image]

There are several blogs that talk about how to do this too. For example:

http://www.ryannitz.org/tech-notes/2009/08/09/create-amazon-ec2-ami/

Finally, if you are registering and EBS backed AMI you can just simply use:

```
ec2-create-image <instance id>
```